# Add an element to HTML and read it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
var row =  "<div class="camera_rec_mode" style="text-align: center;"><img class="img_state center" title="Recording Always" src="/static_media/img/rec_always_.png" alt="1"><div class="rec_state_edit" style="text-align: center;padding-top:10px;"><img class="state_dropdown" src="/static_media/img/dropdown.png" width="23/"></div></div>"
```

What I want to do is to add an element to this HTML to store a value and then read this value.
I have tried this by adding the following to it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="isPtz" id="isPtz" value="true">
```

So it becomes:

```
var row =  "<div class="camera_rec_mode" style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" name="isPtz" id="isPtz" value="true"><img class="img_state center" title="Recording Always" src="/static_media/img/rec_always_.png" alt="1"><div class="rec_state_edit" style="text-align: center;padding-top:10px;"><img class="state_dropdown" src="/static_media/img/dropdown.png" width="23/"></div></div>"
```

And then doing

```
var isPtz = $('.isPtz', row);
```

but in Chrome debugger this gives:
e.fn.e.init[0] which is basically empty.

How can I add then extract an elements value from this HTML??

Comment: If that's your code, then you've got sytax errors due to unescaped `"` characters.

Comment: not sure how you're trying to add html, but if you're trying to insert it dynamically, you need to make your JS dynamic also, your JS is loading before the element is inserted maybe?  In ASP.NET this is handled with scriptmanager.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to add the additional element onto your existing row value, after the page is loaded?

Comment: you are using a class selector '.' to retrieve an element by id '#'

Comment: The HTML is loaded elsewhere, I shortened it to "var row=" for the purpose of asking this question.  I have changed it to use the# and now I get data but it's not "true" its e.fn.e.init[1] which contains lots of other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've selected it you need to access it's value property

```
var isPtz = $("#isPtz", row);
var value = isPtz.prop("value");
```

I've used it's id like Andreas suggested to select it.

Answer (score 0):

The js:

```
var newitem = '<input type="hidden" name="isPtz" id="isPtz" value="true">';
$('.camera_rec_mode').prepend(newitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an id, not a class, so your selector should have `#isPtz`, not `.isPtz`

Also, if you want to add that html into the DOM, it sounds like you want to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or something similar, i.e.

```
$('#isPtz').append(row);
```

I do not know how you would like to add the HTML, your situation, and your goal though - the wording of your post is vague at best.